# How to Extract Title value from selenium in Python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

I want to get `title` value from this through selenium but I am unable to do that. Need expert opinion.

[image: 1]

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for item in items:
    followers = link.get_attribute('title')
    print (followers)
```

it is showing me an empty string. Why is this so?

Comment: There would be many `li` .Try `find_elements_by_partial_link` so narrow down to your requirement.

Comment: You are searching title value in link instead search in item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the below xpath

```
//li//a[@href='/cristiano/followers']
```

is unique in `HTML-DOM`, then you can use the below code:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
try:
    a_tag = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li//a[@href='/cristiano/followers']")))
    print(a_tag.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//descendant::span").get_attribute('title'))
except:
    print("something went wrong")
    pass
```

You do not really need a loop for this use case.

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Steps to check if element is unique or not:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.